# Flash Builder 4.5.1 published android app does not run

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, flash-builder

Mobile application runs perfectly in the debug mode - I can test it on the device etc... The problem is with the release build - it simply does not run. When I manually install .apk I don't get any errors messages, simply a green check mark and "Application not installed" message. Any thoughts?

Running the latest version of air and Flash Builder 4.5.1

Comment: Getting a big closer... Compiled .swf using mxmlc, then manually packaged .apk without any issues... When I try to run: adb install -r myapp.apk: I get the following error:

 pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: as @J_A_X pointed out the problem manifested itself through logs... The problem was with signing (.p12) certificate. As soon as I created a new certificate everything worked smootly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100%, but if I remember correctly, you need to uninstall the old application before installing the new one because of a name collision.  Try that.

Comment: Tried compiling with "adt", everything compiles without issues but the package still does not install. Any other suggestions?

Comment: the crazy part is that I can compile production version for IOS without any issues... So the problem must be with the android wrapper...

Comment: as @J_A_X pointed out the problem manifested itself through logs... The problem was with signing (.p12) certificate. As soon as I created a new certificate everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and regenerating my p12 certificate fixed it.